# Remove animation for Sticky headers for RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am using [this](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) library for Sticky headers with `RecyclerView`. In this library we have animated headers, but I don't need that animation. How to remove that animation. Can anybody suggest how o do this.

Comment: what kind of animation u want to remove?